# Background image bottom gradient with CSS3

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I need this type gradient in the bottom of a background image

[image: Gradient example]

I can't figure out – how to I can make this type gradient with CSS. I've uploaded my code in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLhf9on0/2).

```css
.single-blog-bg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
}

.single-blog-bg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 10%, white 30%, white 60%, white 100%);
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="single-blog-bg" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT8SR.jpg)"></div>
```

Here showing **white** gradient but not like what I expect.

Has there anybody who will help me to get the exact CSS code?

Comment: The JS Fiddle link- https://jsfiddle.net/sLhf9on0/2/

Comment: codepen link- https://codepen.io/djmayank/pen/vJyoVe

Comment: both gradient and image can be set together . first the gradient, then the pic. https://jsfiddle.net/sLhf9on0/5/

Comment: gradient (top to bottom) transparent to white

Answer (score 3):

Add This Style to Image:

```
mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.single-blog-bg {
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative; 
    }
.single-blog-bg:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /*top: 300px*/
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04) 70%);
    /* opacity: .5; */
    height: 100%;
}
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="single-blog-bg" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495935225637-fa5838607df7?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0), white 100%);` for the bottom `div`.

I fork your jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ga57y3n9/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the gradient needs more height- http://prntscr.com/g4np90

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background like this.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
```

Check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdogjG) here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using alpha in the color?

Change the gradient rule to something like this:

```
.single-blog-bg:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 100%);
}
```

*Edit: Remove the opacity property, change the bottom color alpha and give the effect more height*

Comment: Needs more height of the gradient. That mean it should cover more area.

Comment: @user7329515 Change `top: 100px` to give it more height. Edited the response with the change

Answer (score 0):

Try changing css- 
i have done for you

```
.single-blog-bg {
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;    
}
.single-blog-bg:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
  display: flex;
    left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0, 0, 0) 30%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 100%);
  opacity: .5;
}
```

do check- https://codepen.io/djmayank/pen/vJyoVe